# java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

Tags: ssl, keytool

I am using command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "X\cert.pfx" -srcstorepass password -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore "X\keystore3.jks" -destkeypass password -deststoretype JKS -alias alias
```

and get `java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect`

However if I double click on `cert.pfx` and during installation process enter passphrase which is `password` I successfully install it.

Another strange thing is that I am asked for a new keystore passphrase even thought I have supplied it with `-destkeypass password`

**Update:**

Strange thing happened out of nowhere: I was unable to use keytool anymore - I got `This app can’t run on your PC`. After calling `where keytool` I went to that directory and saw that `keytool.exe` is of size 0KB. All I was doing this time was jus trying different versions of `keytool` and `openssl` commands so I've got no idea why this had happened. Since I could not use that instance of `keytool` anymore I tried using different one as I have installed multiple JDK instances on my machine and I it worked: I mean I do not get `keystore password was incorrect` error anymore. I get another error now but it is a different story.

Comment: Are you really using `password` or is that redacted ? If it actually contains non-ASCII characters, their encoding may vary depending on your environment(s) (system, shell or command processor, desktop, etc) which you didn't identify. There are _two_ passwords for JKS, which can be different but usually are made the same: `-deststorepass -destkeypass`. You supplied only the second.

Comment: This is a copy-paste of a command that was executed and only the directory is redacted. Here is a remporary link to the .pkx file https://easyupload.io/lubf1x.